# How can I start a Google Fit Activity from my Android app?

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

How can I start a Google Fit Activity from my Android app, so I don't need to create this screen myself: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DsUA.png
Assuming that Google Fit is installed, is it possible?

Comment: I haven't tested this nor worked with the Google Fit API, but it looks like you should be able to do what you're wanting with this from the API doc: https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a "Session" using Session API in your app. elow link might be helpful:

https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions